Azure keyvault naming convention for using devops pipeline filetransform task
Short story; trying to setup a devops release pipeline which retrieves secrets from an azure keyvault and filetransforms the secrets into our appsettings.json and web.config, but naming conventions in the azure keyvault makes this harder.
Longer story: Our current setup is running onprem through IIS on a windows machine, and all our secrets are commited to our git in the appsettings.production.json... And I want them out of there and into a secret vault for safe keeping.
To complicate the matters further we have about 20 releasepipelines that do almost the exact same things, except deploy to different IIS sites, this is because every developer and tester has their own environments to run this in.
The whole thing is quite messy and our future plans is to move into Azure where there is a better way to do this. But that is at least a year away, and I want the secrets out of our git repository asap.
So back to the issue I am having: I am working on/editing a devops release pipeline that reads secrets from an Azure Keyvault, and performs the FileTransform task on the 'appsettings.json' file, but no values are replaced.
I believe it's because of naming convention, FileTransform:Json wants a dot (.) as a separator, but the keyvault will only let me use a hyphen (-).
So my appsetting:
{
    "AppSettings":
    {
        "Username": "<hidden>"
    }
}

will not be replaced with the secret called
 AppSettings-Username

So the question is either, what can I do differently, or what should I call my secrets?
I know I could use the pipeline 'Variables' part to store the secrets, but this is less secure and also we have 20 pipelines and I don't want to have the secrets written down 20 different times because that is a recipe for disaster.
Another option is to move the appsettings.production.json onto the servers, and store them when I deploy, but again I want better control of the secrets. I just don't want them in our repository.

"So long story short" .. no please. make the story longer.  Where is the application being hosted? For instance, Azure App Service supports things like key vault connection strings. Why would you try and inject / file transform secrets into the appsetting.json file, instead of configuring the host with the appropriate environment variables which will override appsettings?

I added some more details. To summarize, we are running onprem and there is at least 20 different pipelines to deploy to different environments like testing, preprod and prod.... It's a mess.

You can link the Azure key vault to a variable group and linked it to variables in pipeline.
variables:
  - group: KeyVaultVariableGroup
  - name: AppSettings.Username
    value: $(AppSettings-Username) 

Or you can use the replace token task instead of the File Transform task.
You can refer Azure DevOps file transform with vault secrets for more detailed steps.

Very nice solution. Will look into this tomorrow, but looks like this will to the trick perfectly.
